# libXrender.so.1 not available, aws lambda using rdkit

Tags: aws-lambda, rdkit

Thanks for putting a pip install of rdkit together.

When I went to run my code i observed

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "./app.py", line 12, in <module> from rdkit.Chem import Draw 
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rdkit/Chem/Draw/__init__.py", 
line 21, in <module> from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D 
ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

normally this could be treated (i think) with

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

based on
albumentations-team/albumentations#415

however, if one wanted to use a docker build (as I do) from some public image such as
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8:1.71.0-20230124190835

I dont think this is possible.

This thread
https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/rdkit-discuss/thread/CAEmzeFe9Kn6FNeOXmwZqxcdbm7LV1Vz-J9rTw_CJJJRAHgkKfQ@mail.gmail.com/
recommends using a specific conda forge channel.

My plan is to rebuild the docker image using the miniconda base image. I suspect that this might not play well with AWS Lambda/Serverless approaches to app deployment.

I will report back with my workaround. Please let me know if I have missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I am using rdkit-pypi, made an issue here https://github.com/kuelumbus/rdkit-pypi/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

Core issue was that the base docker image that i chose did not include the libxrender1 package nor the apt-get install command. Setting based image to

```
FROM python:3.8
```

resolved the issue